# How can I run a IE window without tabs and menus?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, internet-explorer, popups

Is it possible to run from the command prompt an Internet Explorer window which does not contains tabs and menus (popup window)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you don't want the address line either, you can run it in kiosk mode:
***iexplore.exe -k*** 
This will remove all menus and tabs and run the app full screen with no outer frame.  (This will require you to close the app via the Task Manager).

Or if you just want to disable the toolbars and other addins, use:
***iexplore.exe -extoff***
However, this will not disable the tabs.

Comment: It is very close to what I need. The only disadvantage of the "-k" option is the full screen mode.

Comment: Yea, unfortunately I am not aware of a good "in between" mode.

Comment: This is the main reason I run Firefox. I don't have to have tabs displayed unless I have more than one Tab opened - I don't want to waste screen real estate and have the visual distraction if I don't have to.